# How can I execute a shell command?

Tags: serial

[This page](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=38627.0) says to run a shell command I need a "proxy code" running on my computer (Linux Ubuntu). What do they mean by this, and how should I make one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the term *proxy code,* but I'm assuming that it's a piece of code on your computer that acts as a man in the middle.

You cannot directly use Arduino to run a shell command, so you'll need to create a program on your computer that listens to **[serial](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/serial)** and then executes a command.

For the "proxy code" Python would be a good choice because of the **[pySerial library](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)** that plays nicely with Arduino. It seems [fairly easy to execute a shell command with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).

As per the Arduino code, something like this would work good:

```
setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

loop() {
  if(state == true) {
    Serial.print('A');
  }
}
```

Comment: Some should direct the Pythonic Side Too